# Freelancing for US clients as a US citizen with a foreign company

Tags: taxes, usa

I am a US citizen, but a permanent New Zealand resident. I own my own company here (it's just me in the company), as it allowed me to not pay the self-employment tax America wanted to charge me for contracting with NZ companies. I have been thinking about doing some freelancing work with US companies, but fear it may be way more of a headache than its worth. Either way, my questions are:

1) Can US companies pay my NZ company through Paypal without me setting up a company in the US or somehow registering my company with the US?

2) What are the tax implications for the US side if a US company can pay my NZ company for freelance work? i.e. Will I need to file quarterly taxes or corporate taxes with the US?

I know what happens on the NZ side, but am having real trouble finding out what happens and what the tax implications are on the US side. Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

1) of course US companies can hire a non-US company. Unless The Idiot Formerly Knowm As Trump passed some new law that I am not familiar with restricting any business with non-US companies. (which he didn't, many of his companies use non US contractors)

2) No you don't. You pay taxes in NZ. That's why everybody hates Apple and Starbucks for having companies in Ireland, you pay taxes where you earn.